# Can I specify the list of types for a variant using traits?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variant, crtp

I'm experimenting with some static polymorphism techniques and c++17 templates. I've managed to achieve the polymorphism using CRTP, and then used a container of variants to store my types, so that they wouldn't need a common base class (this would take me back to run time polymorphism).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <variant>

template <typename T>
class Animal
{
public:
    virtual ~Animal() = default;
    void noise()
    {
        derived()->noiseImpl();
    }
private:
    void noiseImpl()
    {
        std::cout<<"Animal animal!\n";
    }

    T* derived() {return static_cast<T*>(this);}
};

class Dog : public Animal<Dog>
{
private:
    friend Animal;
    void noiseImpl()
    {
        std::cout<<"Woof woof!\n";
    }
};

class Cat : public Animal<Cat>
{
private:
    friend Animal;
    void noiseImpl()
    {
        std::cout<<"Meow meow!\n";
    }
};

template <
    typename T,
    typename TD = std::decay_t<T>,
    typename = typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Animal<TD>, TD>>
    >
void pet(T&& animal)
{
    animal.noise();
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::variant<Dog, Cat>> animals;
    animals.emplace_back(Dog{});
    animals.emplace_back(Cat{});

    for (auto& a : animals)
    {
        std::visit([](auto&& arg) 
        {
            pet(arg);
        }, a);
    }
}
```

The example above behaves as you would expect, however what I would now like to do is not need to specify the types of the variant. Instead I would like the compiler to determine all types that inherit from Animal and create a variant that can hold all of those types. This would be similar to what the `pet` function is doing with the use of `is_base_of` by only allowing animals to be passed to the function. I'm not sure if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible to *determine all classes that inherit from a base class* automatically. Generally, it is not achievable, since different inherited classes can be defined in different compilation units.

What you can do is to "register" these inherited classes in some MPL type sequence and use it then to define your `variant` type. For instance with `boost::hana`:

```
constexpr auto types = boost::hana::tuple_t<char, short, int, long>;
using variant = decltype(boost::hana::unpack(
   types, boost::hana::template_<std::variant>))::type;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<variant, std::variant<char, short, int, long>>);
```

Which in your case would be:

```
constexpr auto types = boost::hana::tuple_t<Dog, Cat>;
```

Comment: Ah this looks handy, but what I'm trying to allow for is that user defined types that derive from Animal can be stored in the container, without having to specify all of those types upfront. Similar to storing them using `Animal* ` , but I'm seeing if I can avoid using run time polymorphism.

Comment: @nitronoid You can do this with type erasure techniques, see, e.g., http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/oz18T05o/. Runtime polymorphism is not avoided, but it's hidden inside to the user. Look for `std::vector<Object> backpack;` which would be your vector of animals in your case.